# Deny S3 access if the request does not comes from specific role

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, devops, amazon-iam

I have a policy below here:

If the request comes from that role it should give delete access otherwise it should give access denied including IAM users as well.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::abc-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::abc-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::000000000:role/EC2",
                        "arn:aws:iam::000000000:role/Eventbridge"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After trying this Still got access denied I am i doing something wrong here?

I tried deleting that via this command:

```
aws s3 rm s3://abc-bucket/tmp-test-delete

delete failed: s3://abc-bucket/test-delete An error occurred (Access Denied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
```

Comment: Access is denied by default. Therefore, you should only need to `Allow` the permission in desired situations. There is no need to `Deny` anything unless you are wanting to override something that has granted access (eg if an Admin has all permissions, a `Deny` can override it). In general, if you are wanting to give permissions to a specific Role, you should put the policy on the **IAM Role** itself rather than writing a bucket policy.

Comment: You are only showing a `Deny` policy -- is there something else that is granting an `Allow` to permit it to Delete?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I need a bucket policy to deny delete from all users and allow from specific IAM role how it can be achieved?

Comment: Do "All users" already have permission to Delete from the bucket, via another policy on the IAM Users? If so then, yes, you will need to use a Deny policy to override it. If they _don't_ have another policy that grants them Delete permission, then you do _not_ need a Deny policy since S3 is "Deny by Default". Regardless, you should create an Allow policy on the IAM Role that gives it permission to Delete from that S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have two requirements:

#### Allow specific roles to Delete objects from the bucket

This can be done by adding an `Allow` policy **on the IAM Role itself** (*without* using a Bucket Policy). It would look something like:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abc-bucket/*",
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Deny other users/roles from being able to Delete objects on the bucket

Amazon S3 is "Deny by Default". Therefore, if you are not currently granting any IAM Users or IAM Roles the ability to Delete objects off this (or all) S3 bucket, then there is **no need to do anything** -- they will be denied the ability to delete objects by default.

However, if you have an existing policy that grants this permission to users (eg Admin users have `s3:*` permissions on all buckets), then you would need to use the Bucket Policy that you have shown. The `Deny` will overrule the `Allow`, thereby preventing them from being able to Delete objects from the bucket.

However, think carefully about why they were given the permissions in the first place -- it might be that users have been granted too much access and the existing `Allow` policies should be reduced, rather than adding `Deny` policies.